# Как показать имена и фамилии людей которые заказывали что-то в определеный город?

Tags: sql, sql-server

у меня есть 2 таблицы:
 1: `employees` в ней 2 колонки : `FirstName`, `LastName`
 2: `orders` , в ней есть колонка `shipcity`

для того чтобы показать покупателей из мадрида я использую следующий код:
`select firstname, lastname from employees left join orders on shipcity = 'madrid'`
в ответ я получаю таблицу примерно такого вида:
  1) Nancy Blala
  2) Nancy Blala
  3) Andrew Blala
  4) Andrew Blala.

как изменить код чтобы выводились только уникальные имя и фамилия?

Answer (score 1):

все оказалось гараздо проще чем я думал,
достаточно лишь добавить `DISTINCT` чтобы получилось так: `select DISTINCT firstname, lastname from employees left join orders on shipcity = 'madrid'`